# Generate personalized URL to attach to Shopify Confirmation Email

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I want to insert a personalized link to a shopify confirmation email. I need access to the users name, which will be added to the query string, however, it is processed beforehand and not just added in plaintext. Right now, I have some javascript to generate the url for me. By specifying a name, I get something like

```
example.com/api/NJKLDSA8612AS
```

What would be the best way to generate this URL in shopify? Every example I've seen just adds the plaintext variables to a hardcoded url, but this doesn't help in this case.

Comment: can you post the js code you mentioned? if all you need is the name of the customer you can access that in the `customer` liquid object

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm not pasting it plaintext. It is combined with other values such as the current date and an API-token, which are then combined to a JSON-object which again is then encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

You understand that a Shopify Confirmation Email, confirms an order right? So that email goes out once an order is successfully booked. So your only hope is to react to the orders/create Webhook, where you inject your special URL into the order as Metafield resource. Then in the order confirmation email, assuming it goes out AFTER the orders/create Webhook payload is delivered to you, you can hope that your Metafield resource exists, in which case, you just expose your already made link in the email's HTML by rendering that Metafield using Liquid.

Any of that timing not work out for you, you need a plan B involving sending your own emails.

Comment: Of course, that's exactly what I want to achieve. Sounds promising, I'll give that a go!